# clicked.connect() Error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working on Window 10,PyCharm-Python 3.5.2

What I was trying to do: If PB1(push button 1) clicked, open a new window.

Problem: I get an error

```
 self.PB1.clicked.connect(self.Soft_Memory())
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

Since I defined Soft_Memory(), I don't see why Soft_Memory() is NoneType. 
Though on the editor '.connect' gets highlighted and says cannot find reference 'connect' in  'function'

Codes are below. I've erased some part of the code so that its better to see. If anyone need the full code please comment.

SM.py

```
class SM_Window(QMainWindow, QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.initU()

    def initU(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("SM_Window")
        self.setGeometry(10, 30, 850, 850)
```

UI.py

```
import SM

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def Soft_Memory(self):
        self.SF = SM.SM_Window()
        self.SF.show()

    def Buttons(self):
        #Button for SF
        self.PB1 = QPushButton("POP", self)
        self.PB1.setToolTip("POPOPOPOPOPOP")
        self.PB1.move(100, 100)

    def Signal_to_Slot(self):
        self.PB1.clicked.connect(self.Soft_Memory())

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("UI")
        self.setGeometry(850, 850, 850, 850)
        self.Buttons()
        self.Signal_to_Slot()
        self.showMaximized()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `connect()` method expects a callable argument. When you write `self.Soft_Memory()` you are making a call to that method, and the result of that call (`None`, since you don't explicitly return anything) is what is being passed to `connect()`.

You want to pass a reference to the method itself.

```
self.PB1.clicked.connect(self.Soft_Memory)
```

Comment: Is it possible if the function() has 'return something' then I use self.functiun()?

Comment: Only if 'something' is a callable. In general you should specify the slot directly to make it clear what you are connecting to

Answer (score 2):

The answers from @DaveyH-cks and @user3419537 are correct, you should use a reference of the method, instead of calling it:

```
self.PB1.clicked.connect(self.Soft_Memory)
```

However, you might often need to pass arguments on those functions (I certainly do). On those situations, if you need to use args there's a workaround by using [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

```
self.PB1.clicked.connect(lambda: myfunction(self, arg1, True, "example", arg4))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `self.Soft_Memory()` you are calling the method by using the parenthesis. What you want is to reference the method:

```
self.PB1.clicked.connect(self.Soft_Memory)
```