# PyQt5 Crashes while doing any interaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make a simple login/register form using the module LoadUI and QtDesigner but every time I click a button it just crashes with this error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

So at first, I was making the login form which only has one button that calls a function that prints in the console "Successfully Logged in with Email: and Password:" Problem is every time I click on it, It crashes with that error so I reinstalled PyQt5 Designer because I am sure that my code works fine because I am following a tutorial and I created a new UI file thinking that the old one was bugged or something and it worked fine now while adding the button that navigates to the Register form widget and clicking it , It Crashes again i dunno why and it doesn't even wanna show me the Register Ui here is the Code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class Login(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Login,self).__init__()
        loadUi("Login.ui",self)
        self.loginfun.clicked.connect(self.loginfunction)
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.regbutt.clicked.connect(self.gotoregister)
    def loginfunction(self):
        email=self.email.text()
        password=self.password.text()
        print(f"Successfully logged in with email: {email} and password: {password}")
    def gotoregister(self):
        reg = Register()
        widget.addWidget(reg)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
class Register(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Register, self).__init__()
        loadUi("Register.ui",self)
        self.signupfun.clicked.connect(self.signup())
    def signup(self):
        email = self.email.text()
        if self.password.text() == self.cpassword.text() :
            password = self.password.text()
            print(f"Successfully Created Account with email: {email} and password: {password}")
            login = Login()
            widget.addWidget(login)
            widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
        else:
            print("Passwords doesn't Match")
app=QApplication(sys.argv)
window=Login()
widget=QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(window)
widget.setFixedWidth(480)
widget.setFixedHeight(620)
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Also the link with the Login.Ui, Register.Ui and Main.py just in case you needed the Uis to check them out https://www.mediafire.com/file/rgw565l0c32j3k4/Ui.rar/file

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, and not rely on external resources that might become unavailable. I suggest you to run your code in a terminal or prompt and see the traceback of the error. That said: 1. the connection in Register is wrong (the argument of `connect` must be a callable, not the result of the function call; remove the parentheses); 2. please improve your code style, as functions should be separated by a blank line to improve readability, which is a *very* important aspect (see the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: 3. the fact that you followed a tutorial is pointless, as you might be copying something wrong, modifying without knowing what you're doing, or the tutorial might even be wrong, so "I am sure that my code works" is a wrong assumption. In fact, if I recognize the pattern of that code, that is a tutorial that can be find on Youtube, and which is known to provide ***a lot*** of wrong suggestions and bad practices (starting from the fact that you should *not* add a QDialog to a stacked widget, but there are at least a dozen of other *serious* problems in that tutorial).

Comment: @musicamante ye it was clicked.connect

Comment: So i knew what i did wrong 2 hours debugging and i found the error while comparing the code from the tut and mine the only difference is that i typed this ```self.signupfun.clicked.connect(self.signup())``` and it was supposed to be like this ```self.signupfun.clicked.connect(self.signup)```

Comment: i still don't know why i am a beginner after all so why while removing the brackets the code works ?

Comment: It's explained in the question that is suggested as a duplicate (which I suggest you to accept as such): `connect` expects a reference to a callable (the "name" of the function), but if you add the parentheses you're *calling* the function, which will return the result of that function for `connect`. You're actually doing `self.signupfun.clicked.connect(None)`. That said, I strongly suggest you to look for other tutorials, and completely ignore that one.

Answer (score -1):

The Answer is Changeing `self.signupfun.clicked.connect(self.signup())` to `self.signupfun.clicked.connect(self.signup)`
[it was clicked.connect() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793966/clicked-connect-error)

Comment: The question is a duplicate, so please don't add an answer, but accept the duplicate suggestion on top of your post. Note that you shouldn't also add a question in an answer. Please read [ask], [answer] and also review again the [tour]: StackOverflow is not a chat or forum, avoid writing multiple comments if you can write just one (you can edit comments).